# multiple slideDowns toggle two elements

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find a way to slide down a div and change the clicked link text to say "Read less" but only the div below.

```
<h2>Hello World</h2>
<span class="trigger"><a href="javascript:;">Read more...</a>
<div class="toggle_container">Isn't it a sunny day!</div>

<h2>Hello Again!</h2>
<span class="trigger"><a href="javascript:;">Read more...</a>
<div class="toggle_container">Today isn't so sunny.</div>
```

Here's the closest I have gotten, but it does all divs when any of the anchors are clicked.

```
  $(document).ready(function() { 
  $('.toggle_container').hide();

  $("span.trigger a").click(function() {
    $(".toggle_container").animate({ opacity: 1.0 },200).slideToggle(500, function() {
      $("span.trigger a").text($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Read less...' : 'Read more...');
    }); 
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle_container').hide();

  $("span.trigger a").click(function() {
    $(".toggle_container", $(this).parent()).animate({ opacity: 1.0 },200).slideToggle(500, function() {
      $("a", $(this).parent()).text($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Read less...' : 'Read more...');
    });
  });
});
```

You need to pass `$(this).parent()` to limit the selector to only the parent of the link you clicked. Otherwise, it'll include all matching elements.

You are also missing the closing `</span>` i've added them below

```
<h2>Hello World</h2>
<span class="trigger">
  <a href="javascript:;">Read more...</a>
  <div class="toggle_container">Isn't it a sunny day!</div>
</span>
<h2>Hello Again!</h2>
<span class="trigger">
   <a href="javascript:;">Read more...</a>
  <div class="toggle_container">Today isn't so sunny.</div>
</span>
```

You can see the above code running on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kCNCh/)

Answer (score 0):

```
(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.toggle_container').hide();
    $("span.trigger a").click(function() {
       $(".toggle_container").animate({ opacity: 1.0 },200).slideToggle(500, function() {
                $(this).previous('.trigger:first').children('a:first').text($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Read less...' : 'Read more...');
        }); 
    });
});
```

Something like this should work, I hope this will give you an idea how to solve the problem. Try using $(this) to select the .trigger you want. Using the .trigger selector will select ALL elements with class='trigger'.